# Launching Anaconda Powershell Prompt using pywinauto on jupyter lab

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-lab, pywinauto

I've been trying to launch Anaconda Powershell Prompt using `pywinauto` package on jupyter lab. I copied the code from swapy(tried both 64 bit and 32 bit version). It returns a syntax error. Where's the problem?

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
app2 = Application().Start(cmd_line=u'"C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe" -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -Command "& 'C:\\Users\\USER\\anaconda3\\shell\\condabin\\conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate 'C:\\Users\\USER\\anaconda3' "')
consolewindowclass = app2.ConsoleWindowClass
consolewindowclass.Wait('ready')

app2.Kill_()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDy2i.png)

Tried running the code multiple time changing the types of quote unquote single or double. `pywinauto` is installed using `!pip install pywinauto`

Comment: Please post the a error as text not screenshot.

Comment: Why do you want to automate PowerShell commands by GUI automation tool? What is your high level task? Maybe there is better way at all.

Comment: Careful with your quotes: your command contains single quotes, which close the opening quote of your `cmd_line` definition too soon. You need to escape embedded single quotes with a backslash.